# Power of 2 assumption in Divide and conquer

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, divide-and-conquer

Currently doing an Algorithms course in my 2nd year of university (I am a maths student, but thankfully at Warwick University, we have quite a flexible degree). One of the topics we cover is the divide and conquer algorithmic paradigm. Some algorithms we have studied/I have read about are mergesort, max subarray problem, Strassen's algorithm etc.

When analyzing a lot of these algorithms, a simplifying assumption is generally made that the input size is a power of 2 - thus finding time complexity assuming input size is a power of 2. Surely this cannot constitute a general proof because of this assumption?

Comment: [This](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1138/lectures/05/Small05.pdf) link has what you are looking for - they give a proof of why this is done and in what cases is this feasible.

Comment: The question was already asked and answered on this site. Perhaps somebody can find the link.